# Cultural propagation / divulging or

Tags: word-choice

**(A)**

Which one of the following choices work in my example:

**Example:** Christianity started in Israel and then it has spread all over the world. Hence, once some people started .......... the Christianity culture out of the Israel.

> -1- propagating
>
> -2- divulging
>
> -3- diffusing
>
> -4- disseminating
>
> -5- fostering
>
> -6- purveying

**(B)**

and subsequently which one of the choices bellow is used as a fixed expression in AmE to convey the spreading out of a culture e.g. all over the world or in another country or even a society:

> -1-  Cultural propagation
>
> -2- Cultural divulging
>
> -3- Cultural diffusion
>
> -4- Cultural dissemination

PS. another example of it is e.g. when the tradition of the German Christmas pickle becoming popular in the United States.

Comment: The word for the spreading of a *people* outside their original homeland is [diaspora](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Diaspora), When capitalised, specifically the dispersion of Jews outside of Israel from the sixth century bc, when they were exiled to Babylonia, until the present time, but also used more generally. For your section B, *divulging* is completely wrong, and *diffusion* would be unlikely because it normally connotes *dilution/weakening*. Generally speaking, examples like your Xmas pickle would be seen from the "host" perspective as cultural ***imports***.

Comment: German native here: The "German" Christmas pickle is a myth, not a cultural import. There is no gherkin on a typical German Christmas Tree, I promise!

Answer (score 1):

Propagation in both instances is your best bet.

Ideas, philosophies, ideologies and, as in this case, religions, get "propagated" while information gets divulged and disseminated. Diffused doesn't seem like a good word here unless you want to make some chemistry-based metaphor.

Comment: Thanks VCRkid. What about 'foster' and 'purvey'?

Comment: Not 'foster' or 'purvey.'  In addition to the other ideas already mentioned, how about "spread?"